# maven dependency versionioning issue

Tags: maven

I am trying to add the dependency as below to use the version mentioned or the latest.I am expecting maven to take the dependencies with version >= 0.0.1 but maven is failing to resolve the dependencies.If i mention the exact version the dependencies are getting downloaded.

I am using maven 3.5

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.esb.fuse</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>[0.0.1,)</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

maven logs:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building source out Write 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.401 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-22T17:26:21+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project source: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company.esb.source.out:source:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.company.esb.fuse:common:jar:[0.0.1,): No versions available for com.company.esb.fuse:common:jar:[0.0.1,) within specified range -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

Above details are not sufficient to determine the exact problem. But according to your maven logs,

> No versions available for com.company.esb.fuse:common:jar:[0.0.1,)

Note that it says `com.company`, not `com.compant` as you typed in this question.
check your `pom.xml` first and put correct groupId.

If you are still getting the same error, check your local `.m2` folder and confirm that you have at least one artifact with a version which is in the declared range.

**UPDATE** : the error may be in the `maven-metadata` file. check `maven-metadata-local.xml` file placed inside `.m2/repository/com/company/esb/fuse/common`. All versions should be there under `<versions>` tag.

Comment: I can confirm that the 0.0.1 version is available is my local repository.But also i can see there is a folder created [0.0.1,).It seems maven is looking for artifact with version [0.0.1,) and not version 0.0.1 or latest.

Comment: @Ravi did you confirmed that you have correct `groupId` in the `pom.xml` ?

Comment: Regarding the group id it is a typo,i do not tend to reveal the exact group id so changed it in the post.

Comment: @Ravi can you check how maven resolve dependencies by running `mvn -X
dependency:tree `

Comment: Still the same error is the syntax  <version>[0.0.1,)</version> correct?

Comment: Yes, syntax is correct. Then the error should be in the maven-metadata file. check `maven-metadata-local.xml` file placed inside `.m2/repository/com/company/esb/fuse/common`. All versions should be there under `<versions>` tag.

Comment: After deleting the contents from .m2/repository/com/company/esb/fuse/common it is working.Not sure what is the issue.

Comment: Ah, then the issue was in the maven-metadata-local.xml file. when you delete the whole folder that file will be created again